# Why does document.getElementsByName return a NodeList while document.getElementsByClassName returns an HTMLCollection?

Tags: javascript

This seems confusing, but I bet I am missing something fundamental.

Interestingly enough, the W3Schools docs are wrong and say both methods return an HTMLCollection:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp <- incorrect

The Mozilla docs are correct in that byName returns a NodeList while byClassName returns an 'array like' object, aka HTMLCollection.

Found this out when I tried to run forEach on the output of byClassName and it failed.

Comment: There is many errors in W3Schools docs, just do not use this site as a source of informations.

Comment: @KamilNaja is there an easy way to block that site? They almost always show up in the first search result.

Comment: FWIW, the historical context is that the various parts of the DOM API was created by different people at different points in time (Netscape, Mozilla, Microsoft, Apple etc.) and the W3C standards committee tend to take the position of adopting an existing implementation into the spec wherever possible so the minimum number of developers need to change their browser's behavior. Also, at some point Apple got frustrated with it and started a new standards committee with Mozilla: WHATWG which is not merged back in with W3C standards.. Standards are a messy thing

Comment: @JoshuaDance I tend to start my search with 3 letters: "MDN" to get Mozilla's docs or if you prefer Microsoft add another letter: "MSDN". This avoids returning results from w3schools

Comment: [Why not w3schools.com?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478)

Answer (score 3):

In short, because the specification says so. For [`getElementsByName`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-document-getelementsbyname):

> The `getElementsByName(name)` method takes a string name, and must return a live **NodeList** containing all the HTML elements in that document that have a name attribute whose value is equal to the name argument (in a case-sensitive manner), in tree order. When the method is invoked on a Document object again with the same argument, the user agent may return the same as the object returned by the earlier call. In other cases, a new NodeList object must be returned.

For [`getElementsByClassName`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname):

> The `getElementsByClassName(classNames)` method, when invoked, must return the list of elements with class names classNames for `this`.

(where `this` is usually `document`), and where the "list of elements" is constructed [by](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-getelementsbyclassname):

> The list of elements with class names classNames for a node root is the **HTMLCollection** returned by the following algorithm.....

Similarly, `querySelectorAll` returns a *static* NodeList.

> Interestingly enough, the W3Schools docs are wrong

Not surprising - w3schools is notoriously not very reliable. Better to reference MDN or official specifications.

It's important to keep in mind the difference between the collections. On recent browsers, like you've encountered, there exists a `NodeList.prototype.forEach` method. No such method exists for HTMLCollections. Some of the collections are static, while some are live. The live collections (like with `getElementsByClassName`) can mutate themselves *while you're iterating over them* (unlike static collections and arrays), but the static collections (like with `querySelectorAll`) won't mutate themselves.

But, note that although only NodeLists have a `forEach` method, *both* collections have a `Symbol.iterator` property which you can iterate over with `for..of`:

```js
for (const elm of document.getElementsByName('foo')) {
  // ...
}
for (const elm of document.getElementsByClassName('foo')) {
  // ...
}
console.log('No errors');
```

Comment: Because static collections behave much more predictably than live collections, and because NodeLists have a `forEach` method, I've gotten into the habit of always using `querySelectorAll` to select elements, when possible, because it returns a static NodeList. (qSA is much more flexible than any of the other methods, too)